# "Important to me" or "Important for me"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I cannot easily figure out which one is more appropriate to use:

> It's important *to* me.
>
> It's important *for* me.

Are they the same? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 38):

The simple explanation is that "*important to*" is something you value, while "*important for*" is something you need, or that will help you in some way.

A nice example is:

- "*It is important for you to get well*" ~ your life will be improved
  by returning to health
- "*It is important to your family that you get well*" ~ they put a high
  value on you being healthy.

There is a large grey area, particularly if you are talking about personal experiences. Passing an exam, for example, is something you put a high value on (or you would never have started the course) and will also benefit you in terms of career.  In this case, it is '*important to*' and '*important for*' you.

Comment: This. I was going to type something similar. "Important to me" is subjective and you're informing the listener that you believe this is important. "Important for me" means there's a third party that has dictated that this is important, be it a boss, society or parents.

Answer (score 4):

The word *for* is used to address the object, target or use of an action/activity. It's also used for rightness.

> 'Important **for**' me - in my opinion, this is essential. 
>   
>   *Getting this job is very important **for** me, I'm in great financial crises.*

On the other hand,

> 'Important **to**' is to show the *direction toward* - I'm the receiver, it'll affect me. 
>   
>   *My kid's education is very important **to** me, I'll put her in the best school in the town.*

Comment: "My kid's education is important for/to me" seem to be saying the same thing. What is the difference, if any? I sked a similar question 6 months ago [Its an interesting topic for me versus its interesting to me](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/its-an-interesting-topic-for-me-versus-its-interesting-to-me-does-it-real)

Answer (score 2):

In most cases the *to* part would work for the *for* one but not the other way around. In your example, they probably means the same thing. But if you are picky, the first one means that whatever you are talking about is important to you because it's affecting you. In the second one you are merely expressing your thoughts and the thing may or may not affect you.