# What is different between "for" and "to"?

Tags: prepositions

> 1. The place is important **for/to** me.
> 2. I changed the variable **for/to** the project.
> 3. I can do **to/for** you.
> 4. **In/for/to** this project, I created a new method.

Does it mean any difference?

This bothered me many times.

Wish someone can answer.

Comment: There are two posts that could answer your first question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/important-to-me-or-important-for-me, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/expressing-an-opinion-to-me-or-for-me.

Comment: As for the rest of the questions, it might be better to ask them separately. In my opinion, you can apply the guideline for Question (1) to Question (3). I believe that you shouldn't use either *for* or *to* in Question (2), perhaps *in* might fit, but I'm not sure about what or which variable you are talking about. As for Question (4), if you have developed a new method (for example to cure a disease) while you were working on a project (funded by some foundation, for example), perhaps a rephrase to *While I was working on this project, I developed a new method*.

Comment: ... On the other hand, if you are talking about a method in your computer program, the *in* or *for* might be possible, but then again, it will depend on what you intend to mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the use of 'to' or 'for' usually *does* change the meaning of your phrase, and the difference can be quite big.

To look at your examples:

> The place is important for/to me.

Here the difference is possibly the smallest. Without having any definite answer on this, I say I feel that in this case 'to' give the phrase a bit more of a personal feel. But both forms convey the same concept.

> I changed the variable for/to the project.

Here, the version with 'to' sounds simply strange to me, I would always go for 'for' if given only these choices. Maybe 'in' or 'of' the project sounds even better though.

> I can do to/for you.

There is a very big difference between doing something *to* someone or *for* someone.
When you do something *to* someone, that person is the (more or less) passive 'victim' of whatever you do. If I ask what you are doing *to* someone, correct answers may include acts of violence :)

Doing something *for* someone does not even necessarily include that person's cooperation, you can buy a ticket for someone, do a chore for someone or buy a gift for someone.

> In/for/to this project, I created a new method.

Here I would never use 'to'. Whether to use 'in' or 'for' depends on whether you created the method inside the project or whether it is a new method created externally, to help with the specific project, in which case you use 'for'.

Answer (score -1):

For relates to person who communicates where as to relates more to recipient.