# The tricky prepositions (for vs to) in English

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, american-english, british-english

I have been learning English for the some time now. I get confused between *for* and *to* sometimes. I was reading an article on Yahoo and found out that the writer used the preposition *to*. But I think the writer could also use the preposition *for* instead of *to*. Please check the article and let me know your feedback.

> **In the article**
>
> I usually wake up at 6:30 and go jogging. I eat basically the same
>   things for breakfast and lunch, keep regular office hours, and
>   typically go home to make dinner with my husband, before retiring at a
>   reasonable hour.
>
> These routines are important **to** my success, but no matter how much I
>   enjoy my job and family, sometimes keeping things too routine can make
>   it feel like work.
>
> **As per my opinion**
>
> I usually wake up at 6:30 and go jogging. I eat basically the same
>   things for breakfast and lunch, keep regular office hours, and
>   typically go home to make dinner with my husband, before retiring at a
>   reasonable hour.
>
> These routines are important **for** my success, but no matter how much I
>   enjoy my job and family, sometimes keeping things too routine can make
>   it feel like work.

Comment: possible duplicate :  http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/14484/2818

Comment: Laure has it here I think.  'For' in your example implies that the routines are an essential ingredient for success, whereas 'to' implies that they are only a contributing factor.