# What's the difference between For and To?

Tags: prepositions

Here's an example I'm trouble in.

> - English is important for me.
> - English is important to me.

Can anybody tell me which one to use?
If it depends on adjective, will you teach me it?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/14484/44824

Comment: It might depend on the adjective. It might also depend on the subject. _This meeting is very important to me_ – that means the speaker feels that it's important to have the meeting for some reason. _This meeting is very important for me_ – that means the speaker stands to get some personal gain as a result of the meeting (maybe they will discuss pointers for an upcoming job interview, for example).