# Confused: Use of Important to and important for

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have seen a sentence in book

> Bacteria are important to human health

I have searched on [stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/224342/346804)

And according to that answer -

To is used  as : It is important to me

For is used as: It is important for my health.

So, as per above answer, it should be `Bacteria are important for human health`

Comment: There's a strong tendency to favour [*are important **to** X*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+important+for+me%2Care+important+to+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20important%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20important%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0) where ***X*** is some kind of "conscious entity" (such as ***me***, in that link), because in such contexts we can interpret the statement as meaning ***X thinks** that something is important*...,

Comment: ...but if ***X*** is [just an abstract concept such as ***health***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+important+for+health%2Care+important+to+health&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20important%20for%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20important%20to%20health%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20important%20for%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20important%20to%20health%3B%2Cc0), as can be seen from that link, there's no significant tendency to prefer one preposition over the other, so your usage distinction isn't *quite* correct.

Answer (score 1):

The cited answer does cover this, and you do answer your own question. "Importance" is a measure of value and therefore relative. It does not mean the same as, for example, "*vital*". "Important *to* me" means important *from your perspective*.

I feel your example is correct because bacteria are important *from a human health perspective*. They are not *vital for life*, but *important to it*.

Answer (score 1):

"Important **to**" suggests that something is important to *someone* as a **value.**

> This house is important to me (It's more emotional, like "I *feel* this house is important to me" or "it means a lot to me").

"Important **for**" suggests that something is important for *something* or *someone* as a **need.**

> This house is important for me...or for you..or for him (It's more rational, like "I *understand* that this house is important for someone's survival.")

See also [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/224342/294113) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22860/74177) answer.

So, I would say "Bacteria are important for human health."