# For and To - difference

Tags: prepositions

I feel confused when I have to choose between 'for' and 'to'.
For example, if I want to write that ocean garbage is an serious problem, which way should I write,

> "ocean garbage is an serious problem for us."

or

> "ocean garbage is an serious problem to us"?

Comment: Here is my answer: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/important-to-me-or-important-for-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **for** is used to address the object, target or use of an action/activity.

On the other hand,the word **'to'** is to show the direction towards some object.

As per my knowledge,

"Ocean garbage is **a** serious problem for us." should be considered.