# What is the difference between "pleasant for" and "pleasant to"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

A report of some of the sentences I found on Google with "pleasant for" and "pleasant to" follows:

**Pleasant for**

> - What is **pleasant for** them is what matches their states
> - Hence too, arguing in court and competitive debating are **pleasant for** people who have experience and ability

**Pleasant to**

> - It is not **pleasant to** those who do not like it
> - It is immediately **pleasant to** everyone possessing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nuance lies in *adjective + to* and *adjective + for*. I'll try to address that. [I had answered this here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/important-to-me-or-important-for-me), but this time, I'll be clearer.

Of course, it all depends on the context. Many times, using *to* or *for* with those adjectives may go unnoticed because, ***broadly,*** to many, it may mean the same and convey the message without any ambiguity.

In such sentences, *'for'* connotes the fulfillment of some requirement/need; *'to'* is just an indication of direction toward.

*Important to, pleasant to, good to....* etc talks about how things *'appear'* to you. And using *'for'* talks how actually they are.

Compare:

> Some people are good *to* you, but they might not be good *for* you!

Furthermore,

> A fever-pill may not good *to* you (it tastes yuk!) but then, if you have pyrexia, it's good *for* you!