# What is the difference between interesting to you and for you

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I want to know what is the difference between these two examples:

.1 Read a lot of books that are interesting to you.

.2 Read a lot of books that are interesting for you.

Comment: You could say "Read lots of books.."

Comment: By the time you read through this ELL question, you will get the hang of it. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7180/its-an-interesting-topic-for-me-versus-its-interesting-to-me-does-it-real